# Multiple Threads Writing to a Socket

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I created a TCP client application and decided to handle incoming data with a new thread using the pthread library in c.

However, I read somewhere that unexpected things could happen when multiple threads try to write to the same file descriptor for a socket connection.

what is the best approach to ensure these 'unexpected things' don't happen.

Is there even a need to using threads in the first place?

NB: My decision to use threads was to prevent any blocking operations.

Comment: The best approach is to make sure that only one thread reads/writes the socket. NB: before deciding to use threads, you need to explain why blocking is undesirable.

Comment: Vote to close: too broad

Comment: The application is a USSD application - Unstructured Supplementary Service Data. It will serve multiple users dialing a short code sometimes almost at the same time. The USSD gateway has a timeout in effect and it is required that client applications provide a response within this time frame. User experience will drastically be affected when they have to wait and sometimes their requests may time out.

Comment: @OladipoOlasemo Do you know [`select()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)?

Comment: Yes. I read about it. Not sure how to implement it in actual code.

Comment: [facil.io](http://facil.io) is designed for servers, but you can use it for a client as well. It will provide you with an evented design, allowing for both multi-threaded and single threaded non-blocking operations... there are others out there that will make your life easier.

Comment: You can have as many threads as you like writing to a socket, but that doesn't in any way eliminate blocking. If one blocks they will all block. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I noticed the client app closes the socket randomly. I have not been able to find out why. I read somewhere that it could be a direct result of multiple threads writing to the socket at the same time - sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't - when it doesn't I assume the app crashed and socket closed. but i have no direct evidence for this. Is it okay to have multiple threads writing to a socket without using a queue of some sort or perhaps multiplexing?

Comment: It's OK as long as you don't mind possible data interleaving, but it doesn't solve your actual problem. You should certainly know why your own code closes a socket.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use blocking operations, or lock the one socket?  You're communicating across a network where the latencies are significantly larger than any performance impact on your application.  And there are almost certainly blocks/locks in the socket implementation anyway.

Comment: @EJP I totally agree. I must must know why it closes a socket

Comment: Your code closes the socket: you only have to read the code to find out why. Are you using the right words? Do you perhaps mean that it randomly encounters *connection* resets?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid blocking, you should research asynchronous operations. You can either learn how your particularly platform handles them, or use a library, such as ASIO (https://think-async.com/) which will handle it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Might I recommend using libuv?  It's highly maintained (core of node.js) and cross-platform.

Also, you should not use `select()` that's old school. If you did it yourself you should use `epoll()` on Linux. It scales *much* better.

You should only have one writer thread ever. That thread should write when the socket is not busy.

Checkout libuv - it handles all this messiness for you but still keeps you close to the metal. https://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/networking.html

My approach on stuff like this is to typically have one writer thread, and a fast reader callback, usually just allocating memory for the incoming data, which then just delegates to 1 or more processing threads. If you want it fast avoid `memcpy` at all cost, and allocate a big buffer to began with.

Answer (score -2):

- Yes, you need to create threads if you want to do anything else while waiting for incoming TCP data
- Yes, you need to take care of unexpected things that may happen  in a multi threaded programs

You should use Mutexes to prevent the so called unexpected things. the `pthread` library you're using to create threads also contains synchronization primitives.

A sample program may look like this

```
pthread_mutex_t tcp_lock;

void ThreadFunction()
{
        pthread_mutex_lock(&tcp_lock);
        // Do your stuffs 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&tcp_lock);
}

int MainThread()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&tcp_lock);
    // Do your stuffs
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&tcp_lock);
}
```

Comment: "Yes, you need to create threads if you want to do anything else while waiting for incoming TCP data", no. man select, poll. They are many way to do a server, thread is one of them.

Comment: No, you don't 'need to create threads if you want to do anything else while waiting for incoming TCP data'. You can use non-blocking or multiplexed or asynchronous I/O.

Comment: select, poll , epoll are the best mechanism if you don't want to block your thread when there is no data in socket.